# How do you evaluate exponentiation of church numerals?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Exponentiation over church numerals is defined as:

```
expt ≡ λmnsz.nmsz
```

But I'm having some trouble evaluating it in cases where the power is not 0 or 1. Consider this example:

```
expt C3 C2 ≡ [λmnsz.nmsz](λsz.s^3 z) (λsz.s^2 z)
```

where

```
λsz.s^2 z = λsz.s(sz)
```

and `Cn` represent Church Numeral n

Substituting for m and n, I get:

```
λsz. (λsz.s^2 z)(λsz. s^3 z)sz
λsz. (λsz.s^2 z)(s^3 z)
λsz. (s^3)^2 z
```

And by the fact that

```
λsz. (s^m)^n z = s^(m*n) z
```

the last statement is reduced to

```
C6 ≡ λsz. s^6 z
```

but `expt C3 C2` should evaluate to C9.

So where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
λsz. (λsz.s^2 z)(λsz. s^3 z)sz
λsz. (λsz.s^2 z)(s^3 z)
λsz. (s^3)^2 z
```

You cannot apply (λsz. s^3 z) to sz. You have to apply (λsz.s^2 z) to (λsz. s^3 z), because evaluation is from left to right.

```
λsz. (λsz.s^2 z) (λsz. s^3 z) sz
λsz. (λz.(λsz. s^3 z)^2 z) sz
λsz. (λz.(λsz. s^3 z)((λsz. s^3 z) z)) sz
λsz. (λz.(λsx. s^3 x)((λsy. s^3 y) z)) sz
λsz. (λz.(λsx. s^3 x) (λy. z^3 y)) sz
λsz. (λz.(λx. (λy. z^3 y)^3 x)) sz
λsz. (λz.(λx. (λy. z^3 y)((λy. z^3 y) ((λy. z^3 y) x)))) sz
λsz. (λz.(λx. (λy. z^3 y)((λy. z^3 y) (z^3 x)))) sz
λsz. (λz.(λx. (λy. z^3 y)(z^3 (z^3 x)))) sz
λsz. (λz.(λx. (λy. z^3 y)(z^6 x))) sz
λsz. (λz.(λx. (z^3 (z^6 x)))) sz
λsz. (λz.(λx. (z^9 x))) sz
λsz. (λx. (s^9 x)) z
λsz. (s^9 z)
```